# Unable to access RDS Database via IAM Authentication

Tags: amazon-web-services, go, amazon-rds

I'm unable to connect to my RDS database with an IAM user.

Database username: master
IAM User: api-user

I have assigned the user programmatic access and added following policies to the user:

[image]

The custom rds-permission is defined as: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/UsingWithRDS.IAMDBAuth.IAMPolicy.html

```
    {
   "Version": "2012-10-17",
   "Statement": [
      {
         "Effect": "Allow",
         "Action": [
             "rds-db:connect"
         ],
         "Resource": [
             "arn:aws:rds-db:REGION:ACCOUNT-ID:USER:dbi-resource-id/DB_ACCOUNT_NAME"
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

The strange thing is, even though I have defined my custom permission exactly like it is required in the documentation, it is not recognized:

[image]

[image]

When I'm trying to connect using an authentication token (via golang), I'm getting following error:

```
error: ERROR: Error 1045: Access denied for user 'master'@'x.x.x.189' (using password: YES)
```

My policies don't seem to work!

Even though it is irrelevant, here is how I connect via my IAM user:

```
//Yes Env vars are available
//creating new credentials from environment variables
//AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID  and  AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY
awsCreds := credentials.NewEnvCredentials()

//creating authentication token for the database connection
authToken, err := rdsutils.BuildAuthToken(dbEndpoint, awsRegion, dbUser, awsCreds)
if err != nil {
    Logger.LogFatal("Unable to build Authentication Token")
    log.Fatal("Unable to build Authentication Token")  //todo remove
}

//setting up TLS
mysql.RegisterTLSConfig("custom", &tls.Config{
    InsecureSkipVerify: true,
})

// Creating the MySQL DNS string for the DB connection
// user:password@protocol(endpoint)/dbname?<params>
dnsStr := fmt.Sprintf("%s:%s@tcp(%s:%s)/%s allowCleartextPasswords=true&tls=custom",
    dbUser, authToken, dbEndpoint,dbPort, dbName,
)
rootCertPool := x509.NewCertPool() //NewCertPool returns a new, empty CertPool.

pem, err := ioutil.ReadFile("rds-ca-bundle.pem") //reading the provided pem
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal("! Could not read certificates")
}
fmt.Println("Loading certificate seems to work")
//AppendCertsFromPEM attempts to parse a series of PEM encoded certificates.
//pushing in the pem
if ok := rootCertPool.AppendCertsFromPEM(pem); !ok {
    log.Fatal("Failed to append PEM.")
}
fmt.Println("Appending certificate seems to work too")

//setting up TLS
//we dont need a client ca?
mysql.RegisterTLSConfig("custom", &tls.Config{
    RootCAs: rootCertPool,
    InsecureSkipVerify: true,
})
database, err = sql.Open("mysql", dnsStr)
```

Comment: Presumably you have configured the RDS instance to allow  IAM DB Authentication (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/UsingWithRDS.IAMDBAuth.Enabling.html)?

Comment: Hello! Yes I did. - I have nobody who can help me and I'm sitting on this since 4 days. I beg you for help

Comment: @JulieNoobie The policy statement’s resource shows that you are using “us-west-2c” which is am AZ. Could you please modify that to “us-east-2” i.e. the region where your RDS resource is and try again?

Comment: Do you enable IAM authentication to your RDS instance?

Comment: @sudo I changed it and still doesn't work :(

Comment: @EleazarEnrique Yes, It is enabled

Comment: i'm not familiar with go, but for connecting to mysql with IAM authentication I believe the `--enable-cleartext-plugin` flag must be enabled as well as `--ssl-ca=` with the path to the key file from: https://s3.amazonaws.com/rds-downloads/rds-combined-ca-bundle.pem ... was a pain to figure all this out. good luck!

Comment: @abigperson those flags are available for CLI rather than programmatic access.

Comment: @EleazarEnrique Do you have any suggestions for me? I don't know what to do...

Comment: Are you passing the iam arn `arn:aws:rds-db:region:account-id:dbuser:dbi-resource-id/database-user-name`?

Comment: there should be equivalent methods through any connector to pass any CLI flags, e.g.: https://github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql#allowcleartextpasswords & https://godoc.org/github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql#RegisterTLSConfig

Comment: @abigperson I have added it to my code snippet and it is still not working-

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**According to the sample from AWS Github repository for Go programming language, you need to create the credentials as follow:**

## IAM ARN

**Reference:**  [IAM authentication go example](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/blob/master/example/service/rds/rdsutils/authentication/iam_authentication.go)

```
import (
    "database/sql"
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "os"

    "github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql"

    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/aws"
    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/aws/credentials/stscreds"
    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/aws/session"
    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/service/rds/rdsutils"
)

awsCreds := stscreds.NewCredentials(session.New(&aws.Config{Region: &awsRegion}), iamArn) 

// iamArn: arn:aws:rds-db:region:account-id:dbuser:dbi-resource-id/data‌​base-user-name

authToken, err := rdsutils.BuildAuthToken(dbEndpoint, awsRegion, dbUser, awsCreds)
```

I almost sure you're missing that part of the IAM ARN.

---

## Preparing a Database User

**Reference:** [Preparing a Database User](https://dzone.com/articles/passwordless-database-authentication-for-aws-lambd)

> You need to connect to your database and create a user using the AWS authentication plugin.
>
> The following SQL statement creates a database user named lambda. Instead of specifying a password, the AWSAuthenticationPlugin is used for identifying the user. Replace  with the name of the database you want to grant the user access to.

```
CREATE USER 'master' IDENTIFIED WITH AWSAuthenticationPlugin as 'RDS';
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON <DB_NAME>.* TO 'master'@'%';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

---

## Bonus recommendation

**Reference:** [Limitations for IAM Database Authentication](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/UsingWithRDS.IAMDBAuth.html)

I don't know what's the purpose of IAM authentication in your project, but I consider important the following from AWS documentation:

> ## Limitations for IAM Database Authentication
>
> With IAM database authentication, you are limited to a maximum of 20 new connections per second. If you are using a db.t2.micro instance class, the limit is 10 connections per second.
>
> The Amazon RDS for MySQL and Aurora MySQL database engines do not impose any limits on authentication attempts per second. However, when you use IAM database authentication, your application must generate an authentication token. Your application then uses that token to connect to the DB instance or cluster. If you exceed the maximum new-connection-per-second limit, then the extra overhead of IAM database authentication can cause connection throttling. The extra overhead can even cause existing connections to drop.
>
> ## We recommend the following:
>
> - Use IAM database authentication as a mechanism for temporary, personal access to databases.
> - Don't use IAM database authentication if your application requires more than 20 new connections per second.
> - Use IAM database authentication only for workloads that can be easily retried.
>
> ## Note
>
> For information about the maximum total connections for MySQL, see see Maximum MySQL connections. For information about the maximum total connections for Aurora MySQL, see Maximum Connections to an Aurora MySQL DB Instance.

Comment: Hello. I just tried what the remake the example but it did not work. I think I will just go for an alternative. Can you recommend my any authentication ways? Should I just hardcode the password? Thanks so much for helping me.

Comment: @JulieNoobie you don't need to hardcode the password.  You can authenticate using the common way passing the hostname, port, username, and password through environment variables.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Send me your bitcoin or ethereum wallet. I'll send you a gift.

Comment: At this time, the mysql limitation is **256** new connections per second (not 20).

Comment: @Ele Ok, after a bit of time spent trying to make it work, I have realized that his answer is partially wrong!
The `iamArn` you provided is not correct, it should the arn of the **role you want to assume not the iam user**

Answer (score 1):

The answer provided by Ele is partially wrong this is the correct code:

```golang
arn := "arn:aws:iam::00000000000:role/your-TaskRole"
awsCreds := stscreds.NewCredentials(session.New(&aws.Config{Region: aws.String(Region)}), arn)
```

So the `arn` **is not the one of the iam db user, but is the arn of the role assigned to your resource (EC2, ECS, Fargate)**

Remember that also you **MUST** use TLS to connect to a database via IAM authentication

Answer (score 0):

I was stuck with the same issue. Got it resolved after (a huge lot of lookup online) I added port number for building Auth Token.

Earlier it was like below:

```
authToken, err := rdsutils.BuildAuthToken(host, region, username, sess.Config.Credentials)
```

**Which I had to change to:**

```
authToken, err := rdsutils.BuildAuthToken(fmt.Sprintf("%s:%d", host, 3306), region, username, sess.Config.Credentials)
```

This is for Golang application. But same might apply for other language SDKs.
I got this answer from https://luktom.net/en/e1544-aws-lambda-and-mysql-iam-authentication-in-go

**Someone from AWS need to update their** [official docs on this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-go/api/service/rds/rdsutils/)

Comment: as my understanding `credentials.NewEnvCredentials()` does not work within ECS or EC2